# How this code works in C?

Tags: c

I'm making a program that uses C and ARM assembly, and one of the things I need to do is convert a RGB image into a grayscale image. So my professor gave me this code just to understand how it works:

```
int rgb2gray(pixelRGB pixel){
 return  ( (2048*pixel.R + 4096*pixel.G + 512*pixel.B) /(8*1024));
 }
```

This function converts a RGB value to gray.

Anyone can explain how that algorithm is working and why use those exact values (2048, 4096, 512...).

Comment: Why didn't you ask your professor?

Comment: Because I left the work for the last day haha

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre That's the reason why I'm asking for some help.

Comment: Try it out for some pixel values, and output the result in hexadecimal. Look for a pattern

Comment: the values are pure powers of 2. The program performs a kind of (weighted) average between R,G,B avoiding division except in the end. You can do the same using only adds and shifts (no multiplies) with ARM asm.

Comment: Do you know something about perception of colors? The eye can see green in more tones than red or blue. Therefore the .G part is given more weight. These numbers are just used to put different weight on each color.channel.

Comment: I know nothing about these algorithms and formats, but it would seem that the code is just an obfuscated way of writing the more readable `(pixel.R<<11 | pixel.G<<12 | pixel.B<<9) >> 13`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To convert RGB data into greyscale you need convert 3 numbers into just one. So 2048, 4096 and 512 are just basically weights for each color, i.e. how much each color will impact the grayscale "brightness".

Taking the final division into account, the weights are basically 2/8, 4/8 and 0,5/8. For the integer arithmetic we must multiply first and then divide. That explains the order of operations.

Multiplication and division operations are quite expensive for the CPU, i.e. it is much faster to shift bits than multiply or divide numbers. That is why all the numbers we use is a power of 2. Compiler is smart enough to substitute pixel.B * 512 to pixel.B << 9. In other words, changing a constant to say 6K will slow down the conversion time quite significantly.

Answer (score 3):

Very generally the conversion from RGB to *perceived* greyscale is done using this formula:

```
Y = .2126 * R^gamma + .7152 * G^gamma + .0722 * B^gamma
```

Disregarding the gamma gives us this simplified form:

```
Y = .2126 * R + .7152 * G + .0722 * B
```

If you look closer you'd notice the use of floating-point arithmetic, which is usually **much slower** to calculate than integer operations. So in your example the calculations are re-worked to use integers instead. For instance the first coefficient **0.2126** is represented as **2048/(8*1024)**, which is **0.25**. Not very precise, but *close enough* :)

Answer (score 1):

There are three different constants because green is brighter than red and blue, and red is still brighter than blue.

Asuming 8-bit values for color component values and also the greyscale value, the constants in this function are not well chosen.

One would assume that #000000 (RGB color) becomes #00 (greyscale) and #ffffff becomes #ff.

With the given constants, this is not the case; the maximum greyscale value this function returns is 207. You should replace (8*1024) with something like 6644 to get a better result.

Comment: Replacing (8*1024)  to 6644 will reduce the performance significantly. See my answer for the details.

Comment: @AndriyBerestovskyy I see. In which cases is this tradeoff (more performance but less accuracy) acceptable? Games or something like that?

Comment: We know nothing about the project, but since they use assembler (was mentioned), it is obvious they care more about the performance rather than accuracy.